# Problems installing php5 from source in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, installation

(Originally asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977119/problems-installing-php5-from-source-in-ubuntu)

I've been trying to install php5 for a while.

I'm using.

```
Ubuntu 12.10
Apache 2.4.3
```

And the version of php I want to install is:

```
PHP 5.4.11
```

I follow the documentation in the webpage.

I install Apache (after putting the apr and apr-util folders in ./scrlib, just as the documentation says).

```
sudo ./configure --enable-so
sudo make
sudo make install
```

All of these commands output a lot of information, but no error nor warning as long as I'm aware.

Just for the record:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  http_core.c
  event.c
```

mod_so.c is there, so I think the installation were alright.

Now, I attempt to install PHP (after putting the

```
.sudo ./configure \
  --prefix=/home/usr/local/php5/ \
  --with-mysql \
  --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
  --with-xsl \
  --with-gdbm \
  --with-gd \
  --with-freetype=/usr/include/freetype2/ \
  --with-zlib-dir=/usr/include \
  --with-ttf \
  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib
```

Everything goes fine except the following warning:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-freetype, --with-ttf
```

However, those options aren't the greatest of my problems and I follow to the next steps.

```
sudo make
```

And these are the lasts lines of the output.

```
Generating phar.php
Generating phar.phar
PEAR package PHP_Archive not installed: generated phar will require PHP's phar extension be enabled.
invertedregexiterator.inc
pharcommand.inc
directorytreeiterator.inc
directorygraphiterator.inc
clicommand.inc
phar.inc

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.
```

Next step.

```
sudo make install
```

Everything seems fine.

```
sudo cp php.ini-development /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

I edit the conf file (/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf). The line...

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

...was already there. Just under that line I add:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

I restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

So, php5 should be already installed. I make the following script in php.

```
// info.php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

And saved it in /var/www/info.php

I put the following url in my browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1/info.php
```

There's no output.

In the original question, a user asked me to check the error log (in /var/log/apache2/).

If I browse to my info.php file, the only new line added to the error.log is

```
[Wed Feb 20 19:49:01 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Then they asked me to put display_errors = On in php.ini. Nothing was shown on the screen.

Finally they asked me to run php -i in the terminal. The output was the following:

```
The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

What am I missing? The reason that I don't use apt-get install php5 is because I want all the options I've put in the config file. The first thing that gave me problems was that I did not have the gdbm handler for databases. If you know a way in which I can use apt-get install php5 and then somehow add this new option to php5, then I also consider it a solution.

Comment: Quantal has PHP 5.4.6, why do you need to upgrade it?

Comment: I don't, actually. I just need the gdbm feature.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here, but I suspect you have more than whats visible from what you posted.

The reason why on your terminal you get the message that `php is not installed`, is because the `php` binary is not in your default search path.

according to your `--configure` your php is in `/home/usr/local/php5` (which i personally feel is a weird location). Now if you just enter `php` on the CLI, bash will not check in this directory for the `php` executable, so you have to run it with the whole path. it should be something like `/home/usr/local/php5/bin/php` i think.

If you want to make it available by default with just entering `php`, do this first `ln -s /home/usr/local/php5/bin/php /bin/php`. then Bash should be able to find it by itself if you just enter `php`.

The other problem is that you are using to `configure` parameters which simply don't exist. You can see the available `configure` parameters by doing `./configure --help` in the source directory of php.

I forgot one: for verifying if the php module was loaded in apache or not, you can use apache's mod_info. It tells you which modules were loaded successfully. If you see in the mod_info output that the PHP module wasn't loaded, then you should probably check apaches output on startup. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_info.html

Comment: OK. I've configured without the troublesome options (`--with-freetype=/usr/include/freetype2/` and `--with-ttf`) and recompiled again. Afterwards I added into `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` the lines of code pointed out by the documentation
`<Location /server-info>
SetHandler server-info
</Location>`
Still nothing is shown on the screen. Finally, I was successful executing `/home/usr/local/php5/bin/php -i`, but the output is too long to post it here. What am I looking for?